# Why am I not able to change the title of my action bar?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I tried to change the title of my action bar using the tips given in other answers but they don't seem to work.I am trying to change the title to "test".

Here is the 
activity_detectlayout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.kaushik.abhishek.facedetecto.detectlayout">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/detect_face"
    android:text="@string/detect_face"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#d4424646"
    android:textColor="#fdfffa" />
```

detectlayout.java

```
package com.kaushik.abhishek.facedetecto;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class detectlayout extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActionBar().setTitle("Test");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detectlayout);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detectlayout, menu);
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".detectlayout"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detectlayout" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: show your styles.xml first, it could possibly two reason, one if your using your toolbar, you need to setSupportActionBar, or system get action bar.

Comment: I have tried both but I can't see any change.

Comment: Try to remove android:label="..." from activity at manifest file.

Comment: @oguzhand thanks its working now. But just out of curiosity, why the other answers aren't working in my case ? like getActionBar().setTitle("Test");

Answer (score 0):

Use this on your Activity inside OnCreate method.

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");
```

Or, Change it by Menifest

```
       <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:label="Your Title" />
```

Answer (score 0):

change `getActionBar().setTitle("Test");` to `getSupportActionBar` instead.Because `AppCompatActivity` uses support version.

If you are using a custom version.

```
// Find the toolbar view and set as ActionBar
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

// Display icon in the toolbar
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Comment: did you define any custom toolbar? by any chance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("your title");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detectlayout);
}
```